# Android animation issue

Tags: android, animation, android-linearlayout

Hi i need to move linearlayout from one location to another , and i need him to stay there ,  but animation is not working at all here is the code

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tanim);
    TranslateAnimation ta = new TranslateAnimation(-80, -80, 0, 0);
    ta.setDuration(1000);
    ll.startAnimation(ta);
```

Comment: What do you mean not working? What does it do? what do you want it to do?

Comment: is just stay where he is by default , he wont to move to location that i specified with coordinates ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course that wont work.

The first two parameters are fromX and toX 0 the values you entered tell the View to move from -80 to -80..
Try:

```
TranslateAnimation ta = new TranslateAnimation(0, -80, 0, 0);
```

If you want the view to stay in place after the Animation ends and not return to its original place add:

```
ta.setFillAfter(true);
```